# IdentityServer4 Windows Sign-On under IIS 10 fails to authenticate successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4

Using IIS Express on my local machine, I'm able to run the IdentityServer4 QuickStart UI project and successfully sign in. However, once it is deployed to production, I'm unable to get it to work.

On the Application Pool for the site, I have a domain account setup (with just about every permission possible granted). I have tried every variation of having "anonymous authentication" toggled. I've gone as far as recreating the entire application from scratch in multiple different ways (no-SSL, only-SSL, fully open CORS, all security policies disabled), and even the most basic version of the application seems to suffer from the exact same issue.

After slapping some logging on the application, I can see that I'm grabbing the Subject ID and name from AD just fine.

Here's the `ProcessWindowsLoginAsync` method, with only minimal logging changes.

```cs
private async Task<IActionResult> ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
    if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName },
            }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
        var sub = wp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value;
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, sub));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));
        
        _logger.LogInformation("Assigning claims. Subject {@Subject}. Name {@Name}", sub, wp.Identity.Name);

        if (AccountOptions.IncludeWindowsGroups)
        {
            var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
            var groups = wi!.Groups!.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
            var roles = groups!.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
            id.AddClaims(roles);
        }

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
            props);
        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }

    return Challenge(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
}
```

The above code spits out something akin to (with identifying information stripped):
`Assigning claims. Subject S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-00000. Name DOMAIN\NAME`

Once the above has executed, the external callback method is called and it immediately throws an exception:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("We were not successfully able to sign in. Failure: {@Failure}. None: {@None}", result?.Failure, result?.None);
        if (result?.Failure != null)
            throw result.Failure;
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }

    if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
    {
        var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
        _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
    }

    var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
    if (user == null)
        user = AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);

    var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
    var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
    ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

    var issuer = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
    {
        DisplayName = user.Username,
        IdentityProvider = provider,
        AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(issuer, localSignInProps);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

    var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    
    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.ClientId));

    if (context != null)
        if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

From the logs, I can tell that it's immediately failing after attempting to authenticate. There's no other errors, but a few interesting logs of note (in order):

```
Performing protect operation to key {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b7e4d6dd250a} with purposes ('C:\websites\identity.ourdomain.com', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'idsrv.external', 'v2').

AuthenticationScheme: idsrv.external signed in.

Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /External/Callback

Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController.Callback (Idsvr.Api) - Validation state: Valid

AuthenticationScheme: idsrv.external was not authenticated.

(Exception)
```

Comment: try to change ApplicationPool identity to Domain User Account/Service account.

Comment: @Ravi it's currently using a domain account with nearly every permission granted.

Comment: in your code, signingout the extension login.  

await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

Comment: @Ravi I'm not sure I understand. That particular line is never actually reached. If `Callback` method does not execute beyond the first if-statement block. I'm not sure how the `SignOutAsync` is relevant for this one.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible root cause is that the callback cookie doesn't set properly.
Try to capture the network traffic, and check if idsrv.external cookie has been set correctly during Challenge.
In my case, setting cookie failed because SameSite=None is there without Secure=true.

Comment: It did actually end up being a cookie issue. Specifically, Chrome security settings were not working with a not HTTPS secured site, and as this was purely an internal app, we didn't want to muck around with a certificate. After enabling HTTPS and using LetsEncrypt, the cookies began working as expected.